# Python and Pandas: How to round Up/Down unix timestamp (utc) on different resolutions: 1min-5min-15min-30min-1H-1D?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unix-timestamp, utc

Given the following time resolutions examples, what would be the fastest way to round UNIX time to get the results shown below? Both in simple python and in pandas dataframes?

```
import time
unix_current = int(time.time())
unix_from_down_example = int("1453823631")
unix_from_up_example = int("1453820476")
```

**Round Down/Up to 1 Minute**

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
|               |                     | Unix (UTC) |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:53:51 | 1453823631 |
| to round down | 26.01.2016 15:53:00 | 1453823580 |
|               |                     |            |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:01:16 | 1453820476 |
| to round up   | 26.01.2016 15:02:00 | 1453820520 |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
```

**Round Down/Up to 5 Minutes**

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
|               |                     | Unix (UTC) |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:53:51 | 1453823631 |
| to round down | 26.01.2016 15:50:00 | 1453823400 |
|               |                     |            |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:01:16 | 1453820476 |
| to round up   | 26.01.2016 15:05:00 | 1453820700 |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
```

**Round Down/Up to 15 Minutes**

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
|               |                     | Unix (UTC) |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:53:51 | 1453823631 |
| to round down | 26.01.2016 15:45:00 | 1453823100 |
|               |                     |            |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:01:16 | 1453820476 |
| to round up   | 26.01.2016 15:15:00 | 1453821300 |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
```

**Round Down/Up to 30 Minutes**

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
|               |                     | Unix (UTC) |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:53:51 | 1453823631 |
| to round down | 26.01.2016 15:30:00 | 1453822200 |
|               |                     |            |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:01:16 | 1453820476 |
| to round up   | 26.01.2016 15:30:00 | 1453822200 |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
```

**Round Down/Up to 1 Hour**

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
|               |                     | Unix (UTC) |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:53:51 | 1453823631 |
| to round down | 26.01.2016 15:00:00 | 1453820400 |
|               |                     |            |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:01:16 | 1453820476 |
| to round up   | 26.01.2016 16:00:00 | 1453824000 |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
```

**Round Down/Up to 1 Day**

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
|               |                     | Unix (UTC) |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:53:51 | 1453823631 |
| to round down | 26.01.2016 00:00:00 | 1453766400 |
|               |                     |            |
| from          | 26.01.2016 15:01:16 | 1453820476 |
| to round up   | 27.01.2016 00:00:00 | 1453852800 |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+
```

I used this [website](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)  as a conversion reference for the examples given.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html?highlight=round#datetimelike-rounding its right in the docs

Comment: thanks @Jeff for the reference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic formula for rounding DOWN:

```
n // <Number of seconds> * <Number of seconds>
```

A generic formula for rounding UP:

```
n // <Number of seconds> * <Number of seconds> + <Number of seconds>
```

Function:

```
def round_unix_date(dt_series, seconds=60, up=False):
    return dt_series // seconds * seconds + seconds * up
```

Usage:

```
In [204]: df
Out[204]:
        Date1       Date2
0  1453823631  1453820476
1  1453823631  1453820476
2  1453823631  1453820476

In [205]: round_unix_date(df.Date1, 5*60)
Out[205]:
0    1453823400
1    1453823400
2    1453823400
Name: Date1, dtype: int64

In [206]: round_unix_date(df.Date2, 5*60, up=True)
Out[206]:
0    1453820700
1    1453820700
2    1453820700
Name: Date2, dtype: int64
```

---

Demo (rounding DOWN):

```
In [165]: n // (1 * 60) * (1 * 60)
Out[165]: 1453823580

In [166]: n // (5 * 60) * (5 * 60)
Out[166]: 1453823400

In [167]: n = 1453823631

In [168]: n // (1 * 60) * (1 * 60)
Out[168]: 1453823580

In [169]: n // (5 * 60) * (5 * 60)
Out[169]: 1453823400

In [170]: n // (15 * 60) * (15 * 60)
Out[170]: 1453823100

In [171]: n // (30 * 60) * (30 * 60)
Out[171]: 1453822200

In [172]: n // (60 * 60) * (60 * 60)
Out[172]: 1453820400

In [173]: n // (24 * 60 * 60) * (24 * 60 * 60)
Out[173]: 1453766400
```

Demo (rounding UP):

```
In [188]: n = 1453820476

In [189]: n // (1 * 60) * (1 * 60) + 60
Out[189]: 1453820520

In [191]: n // (5 * 60) * (5 * 60) + 5*60
Out[191]: 1453820700

In [192]: n // (15 * 60) * (15 * 60) + 15*60
Out[192]: 1453821300

...
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [226]: round_unix_date(df.Date1, 24*60*60)
Out[226]:
0    1453766400
1    1453766400
2    1453766400
Name: Date1, dtype: int64

In [227]: round_unix_date(df.Date2, 24*60*60, up=True)
Out[227]:
0    1453852800
1    1453852800
2    1453852800
Name: Date2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you @MaxU for the answer, i accepted it because it scores faster in my tests and it looks so clean and simple:)

Comment: @RaduS, `round_unix_date(df.Date1, 24*60*60)` - gives me correct results

Comment: Could it be something else then, the timezone? i get the following result on the example: `from 1453823631 down to 1487632800 when i should actually get 1453766400`. and `from 1453820476 up to 1487632860 when i should actually get 1453852800`

Comment: I guess you've specified `up=True` parameter? So it rounded it UP

Comment: yes that is correct, i mixed it up in when i copy pasted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any features in Pandas that would help you achieve this task. A good solution would be to just write a Python function which you can then apply to a column of the dataframe using the *apply* function in pandas.

Convert you timestamp column to a datetime object. That should help you get different units of the timestamp easily.

Here is some logic to help you:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

t = datetime(2011,10,15,12,30,15)
```

### Round by 1 minute

Just truncate the seconds field for round down. Add a minute and truncate a second in case of round down.

```
# round down
t_down = t.replace(second=0)

# round up
t += timedelta(minutes=1)
t_up = t.replace(second=0)
```

### Round by 5 minutes

You will have to play with some mod arithmetic here. The below example is for 5 minutes, but you can extend modify this for 15 and 30 minutes simply by replacing *5* by the required amount of minutes.

```
# round down
diff = t.minute % 5
t_sub = timedelta(minutes=diff)
t_down = t - t_sub

# round up
diff = t.minute % 5
t_sub = timedelta(minutes=5-diff)
t_up = t + t_sub
```

### Round by 1 hour

Use the same method as for 1 minute, using hour instead of minute.

```
# round down
t_down = t.replace(minute=0, second=0)

# round up
t += timedelta(hours=1)
t_up = t.replace(minute=0, second=0)
```

### Round by 1 day

Again extend the 1 minute and 1 hour examples.

```
# round down
t_down = t.replace(hour=0 ,minute=0, second=0)

# round up
t += timedelta(days=1)
t_up = t.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```

A good idea would be to create a function for each of the cases you want to handle. Then have another function that calls one of these functions based on the current task that the user wants to carry out.

Comment: Thank you @shish023 for the answer:)